# iOS JSONModel json instance

Tags: ios

I am attempting to use this [JSONModel library](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) in an app I'm building. I've been following [this article](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/), but for some reason I keep getting (null) when attempting to parse the json string. I was told that it is because I'm not creating a json instance; but it seems to me I am. Below is the code, can anyone see what I'm missing? I'm attempting to use [this web service](http://qa.shiftzen.com/ws/schedutils.asmx?op=GetDailyView), with these inputs:
     emailAddress: wufpakjack@yahoo.com;
     password: test;
     companyId: 2579;
     scheduleDate: 20140415.

myShiftModel.h

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@interface myShiftModel : JSONModel

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *shiftName;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *shiftStartTime;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *shiftPosition;

@end
```

dailyViewModel.h

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "myShiftModel.h"

@protocol dailyViewModel @end

@interface dailyViewModel : JSONModel

@property (assign, nonatomic) int numAvailableXChanges;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *todaysForecast;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int todaysTemperature;
@property (strong, nonatomic) myShiftModel *workShift;

@end
```

dailyFeed.h

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "dailyViewModel.h"

@interface dailyFeed : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray <dailyViewModel> *workShifts;

@end
```

mainViewController.m

```
#import "mainViewController.h"
#import "JSONModelLib.h"
#import "JSONModel+networking.h"
#import "dailyFeed.h"


@interface mainViewController () {
    dailyFeed *feed;
}
@end

@implementation mainViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSString *email = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"wufpakjack@yahoo.com"];
    NSString *pass = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"test"];
    NSString *compID = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"2579"];
    NSString *date = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"20140415"];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://qa.shiftzen.com/ws/schedutils.asmx/GetDailyView?emailAddress=%@&password=%@&companyId=%@&scheduleDate=%@", email,pass,compID,date];
    NSLog(@"%@", urlString);

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:urlString
                                  completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {

                                      NSError* error = nil;
                                      feed = [[dailyFeed alloc] initWithDictionary:json error:&error];

                                      NSLog(@"shifts: %@", feed.workShifts);

                                  }];
}
@end
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Warmest regards,
DB

Comment: This web service is SOAP based, so response is XML not JSON.That means that using of JSONModel here  is pointless.

Comment: (You might try checking for error messages.)